# AWS API Gateway proxy endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, gateway

I am trying to implement few already existing APIs.
Suppose i have a application running on server say

> 192.168.0.1:8036

.
It has various routes like

```
http://192.168.0.1:8036/api/sample/a1?name=swas&class=tty
http://192.168.0.1:8036/api/samp/a2?addr=swas&roll=tty
```

Have a custom domain name say

> api.example.com

So here i want to direct every request through AWS Gateway.
Finally request would be like

Request

> http://api.example.com/api/samp/a2?addr=swas&roll=tty

would be passed as

> http://192.168.0.1:8036/api/samp/a2?addr=swas&roll=tty

**Note: There could be multiple Routes with different dynamic parameter**

**In short every request which comes to api.example.com/* should be passed through AWS gateway to 192.168.0.1:8036/***

Comment: And your question is... how to do this?  What are you running at api.example.com? Nginx? Apache? HAProxy? ELB? ALB? CloudFront?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, how to do this? I am running Nginx

Comment: We need to clarify this question, further, because I originally read it... backwards.  I thought you wanted Nginx → API Gateway but now I think you want API Gateway → Nginx.  API Gateway can't access private address space using the HTTP Service Proxy mode.  Your Nginx server must be accessible from the Internet for API Gateway to access it, if this is what you want. But you can secure your Internet-accessible endpoint by configuring API Gateway to [authenticate itself](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a straight forward use of http proxy with a custom domain name.

Documentation for setting up http proxy is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html)

Documentation for setting up custom domain names is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

From your use case description, you'll want to set-up the custom domain name with no base path so that it points to a single API.  You'll also want to specify the stage in the base path mapping so that the caller doesn't have to provide it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Getway has limitation for one custom domain per one REST API. Not sure exactly what the question is here, but you can map multiple base paths, which you will have to define manually. 
double check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)